# Add second network to vsphere terraform plan

Tags: vmware-vsphere, terraform

I would like to add a second network to my vsphere terraform plan, but I cannot seem to figure out how this is added.  My vsphere terraform plan has the following:

```
network_interface {
label = "${var.network1}"
}
```

I would like to be able to add a second network (var.network2).. any ideas on how this is accomplished? Adding a second label seems to overwrite the first one.

Answer (score 1):

You should add one more `network_interface` block to your `vsphere_virtual_machine` resource:

```
resource "vsphere_virtual_machine" "vm" {
  name   = ""
  folder = ""
  vcpu   = ""
  memory = ""
  datacenter = ""
  cluster = ""
  resource_pool = ""

  network_interface {
    label = "${var.network1}"
  }

  network_interface {
    label = "${var.network2}"
  }

  disk {
    datastore = ""
    template = ""
  }
}
```